# MySQL server accessible through public ip but not through internal ip

Tags: mysql, networking, ip

I have two servers running at my business. The first one runs a mysql server and it is dedicated only for mysql. The ip address is `192.168.1.2` and the second server runs wordpress on apache and also acts as a reverse proxy for nodejs. It's ip is `192.168.1.15` When I try to access my mysql server using the public ip from `192.168.1.15` it works fine. But when I try to access the server using internal ip `192.168.1.2` it says cannot connect to mysql server.

```
Ex1
root@192.168.1.15->mysql -u xxxx -h [public ip] -p
root@192.168.1.15->mysql->
Login Success

Ex2
root@192.168.1.15->mysql -u xxxx -h 192.168.1.2 -p
Cannot connect to mysql server
Error
```

When I try to access wordpress website it says

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

And I can't use nodejs website cause it uses mysql to login users

Both nodejs server and wordpress uses `192.168.1.`2 as the host for mysql server

How can I fix this?

Comment: is there any firewall which is blocking the connection in your network?

Comment: @noob No there's no firewall

Comment: Did you check if the port is open or tried telnet for debug ?